# Data display in the PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

//Working Details

```
       PdfPTable tabl2 = new PdfPTable(7);
               // tabl2.TotalWidth = 350f;
                //tabl2.LockedWidth = true;
                //tabl2.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                tabl2.SpacingBefore = 10f;
                bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
                times = new Font(bfTimes, 12f, Font.UNDERLINE);
                para = new Paragraph("Working Details:", times);
                para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                doc.Add(para);
                cell.Colspan = 3;
                cell.Rowspan = 2;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                cell.BorderColor = new BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
                //tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase("Sr.No.", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));

                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase("Working Place", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase("Date Of Joining", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase("Institute Name", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase("Year", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase("Duration", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase("Post held at last", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase("Area of Work", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                string connects = @"Data Source=BOPSERVER;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connects))
                {
                    string query = "select * from Working_det where Fid='" + va+"'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                    try
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {


                                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[1].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToDateTime(sdr[2]).ToShortDateString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[3].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[4].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[5].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[6].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl2.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[7].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                cell.Rowspan = 2;
                cell.Colspan = 2;
                tabl2.AddCell(cell);
                tabl2.SpacingAfter = 30f;
                doc.Add(tabl2);


                //Membership Details
                PdfPTable tabl3 = new PdfPTable(4);
                tabl3.SpacingBefore = 10f;
                bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
                times = new Font(bfTimes, 12f, Font.UNDERLINE);
                para = new Paragraph("Membership Details:", times);
                para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                doc.Add(para);
                cell.Colspan = 3;
                cell.Rowspan = 2;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                cell.BorderColor = new BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
                tabl3.AddCell(new Phrase("Membership Number", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl3.AddCell(new Phrase("Type of Membership", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl3.AddCell(new Phrase("Validity", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                tabl3.AddCell(new Phrase("Remarks", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                string connect = @"Data Source=BOPSERVER;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connect))
                {
                    string query = "select * from Membership_det where Fid=='" + va + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                    try
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {

                                tabl3.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[1].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl3.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[2].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl3.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[3].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                                tabl3.AddCell(new Phrase(sdr[4].ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                cell.Rowspan = 2;
                cell.Colspan = 2;
                tabl3.AddCell(cell);
                tabl3.SpacingAfter = 30f;
                doc.Add(tabl3);
```

The above code shows to diplay the data in a pdf..
my problem is The pdf data will be displayed for working details but not for membership details..The pdf is shown below.I need to retrive the data for the membership details as it is been displayed in the working details

There are no change in the code but data is not retrieved..Please suggest any help for this..

[image: Pdf for the following code]

Answer (score 2):

From a quick inspection of your code, it appears that your 2nd query is not getting any response. Make sure that your database has data in it for your query and that your query returns the data you expect.

Comment: It has some data in the database